# Spring Data Hazelcast Repository not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, hazelcast, spring-data-keyvalue

I try to connect my Springboot(v1.4.2) App with a Hazelcast Cluster to find stored data. For that I'm using a hazelcast-client instance and I created a HazelcastRepository to search my data.

The problem is that my Repository doesn't find any data. It always returns an empty list when I test with findAll() or null when I test with findOne():

Below are my Service/Repository/Domain/Configuration codes:

```
@Service
public class MyService {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyService .class);

    private final MyHCRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    public MyService (final MyHCRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public String get(final String name) {
        List<Element> elements= repository.findByName(name);
        return elements.toString();
    }
}
```

Here is my Repo and domain:

```
@Repository
public interface MyHCRepository extends HazelcastRepository<Element, Integer> {
    List<Element> findByName(String name);
}

@Data
@KeySpace
public class Element implements Serializable {

    private Integer id;
    private String name;
}
```

Here is my hazelcast-client config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableHazelcastRepositories
public class HazelcastConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("client")
    public HazelcastInstance hazelcastClientInstance() {
        final ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
        final ClientNetworkConfig networkConfig = new ClientNetworkConfig();
        networkConfig.setAddresses(singletonList("127.0.0.1"));
        clientConfig.setNetworkConfig(networkConfig);
        return HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(clientConfig);
    }

    @Bean
    public KeyValueTemplate keyValueTemplate() {
        return new KeyValueTemplate(new HazelcastKeyValueAdapter(hazelcastClientInstance()));
    }
}
```

And in my pom, I use these dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
            <artifactId>hazelcast-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-hazelcast</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-data-keyvalue</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hazelcast</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>spring-data-keyvalue</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I got no errors, no exceptions. It's like there were no data in my Hazelcast cluster but I know there is. With my client if I connect and load a Map from the Hazelcast-Cluster like this:

```
client.getMap("mapsName");
```

then I got my Data but if I try to use the Hazelcast Repository, I dont find anything. 
Could someone tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its all good, I found the problem. I just needed to associate the name of my Map with the @Keyspace Annotation inside my Domain class (Element) --> @Keyspace("myMapName")